# How to implement a merge sort for a linked list in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mergesort

I want to implement a [merge sort for a single linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/) in Ruby.

This code is running without any error but doesn't output as  expected.

```
class Node
    attr_accessor :data, :next
    def initialize(value)
        @data = value
        @next = nil
    end
end
```

Merge sort method:

```
def mergesort(head)
    return head if !head || !head.next

    a, b = frontbacksplit(head)
    mergesort(a)
    mergesort(b)
    c = sortedmerge(a, b) #something is going wrong here
end
```

This method is used to divide the list into two sublists:

```
def frontbacksplit(head)
    slow = head
    fast = head.next
    until fast.nil?
        fast = fast.next
        unless fast.nil?
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next
        end
    end
    a = head
    b = slow.next
    slow.next = nil
    [a, b]
end
```

There may be a mistake in this method:

```
def sortedmerge(a, b)
    result = nil

    if a.nil?
        return b
    elsif b.nil?
        return a
    end

    if a.data <= b.data
        result = a
        result.next = sortedmerge(a.next, b)
    else
        result = b
        result.next = sortedmerge(a, b.next)
    end
    result
end
```

Comment: You should provide the link to the complete working program. Put it up as a gist if it's too long for the question. You will get much speedier replies that way, since people can test your code with just a simple copy and paste.

Comment: Kindly check it out https://repl.it/repls/BlindFortunateParallelprocessing as it doesn't output 2

Comment: "This code is running without any error but doesn't output as  expected." So, wouldn't that be a good definition for an error, it's not running as expected? See "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Comment: You may want to consider a bottom up merge sort for linked lists, which can be up to 40% faster on large lists with scattered nodes that don't fit in cache (a cache miss on every node accessed). It eliminates the scanning to split lists and instead uses a small (25 to 32) array of pointers or references to sub-lists. The wiki article includes [example pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `mergesort` method. The original implemantation is defined as:

```
void MergeSort(Node** headRef) 
{ 
   ...
   MergeSort(&a); 
   MergeSort(&b); 

   *headRef = SortedMerge(a, b); 
}
```

This means it is changing the the contents of `a` and `b`.

Since Ruby does not have such call by reference semantics, you simply forgot to assign the result back into `a` and `b` in the Ruby version to duplicate this behavior.

The fix:

```
def mergesort(head)
  ...
  a = mergesort(a)
  b = mergesort(b)
  sortedmerge(a, b)
end
```